# How to suppress emoji in Facebook Messenger Bot - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, emoji, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

does anyone if its possible to suppress an emoji's sent from a facebook messenger bot? I'm trying to send a list and 8) is turning into  on facebook's end.

I'm wondering if theres any known escape characters or if I can encode it somehow (HTML encoding?).

Here is how I'm sending my request.

```
requests.post("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    params={"access_token": token},
    data=json.dumps({
        "recipient": {"id": recipient},
        "message": {"text": "8)"}
    }),
    headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Python 2.7.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with [the 'word joiner' unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2060/index.htm). Here it is, between these arrows: ->⁠<-.

It doesn't work if you send the HTML code, you need to send the actual character.

For example:

```
:⁠)
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! For any anyone else wondering did the trick:
`text = (u'B\u2060)').encode('utf-8') this`